# SQL AND Function working

Tags: sql

How to get Age 55, 25 with AND function in sql.

How to get this done.

```
select * from Age_Table where Age='55' AND Age='25';
```

This query does not work.

Comment: You need  `Age='55' OR Age='25'` Age cant be both values at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query works fine.

What it means to use `Age='55' and Age='25'` is that `Age` should be `55` **and** `25` at the same time, which is impossible. Hence, your query returns 0 rows.

Use `or`:

```
select * from Age_Table where Age='55' or Age='25';
```

Or `in`:

```
select * from Age_Table where Age in ('55', '25');
```

Answer (score 1):

In a single row the column value can not be both - `55` and `25` but only either one. So use `or`

```
select * from Age_Table 
where Age='55' 
OR Age='25';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Age_Table 
WHERE Age IN ('55', '25');
```